# Constrain body text width while allowing pre elements to be wider than their parent if necessary

Tags: html, css

I have a blog article with code samples. For readability, the article's text is constrained to a certain maximum width. The code samples, however, may need to be wider than the maximum width of the text. What's the best way to accomplish this with HTML/CSS?

Here's a basic example illustrating the layout I'm trying to achieve as well as my problem.

```css
body {
  max-width: 650px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}

pre {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This is a sufficiently long paragraph.  Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae hic rei publicae
  vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Ut id aliis narrare
  gestiant? Cur iustitia laudatur? Nummus in Croesi divitiis
  obscuratur, pars est tamen divitiarum.</p>

  <p>This pre should be as wide as the first paragraph, even
  when the viewport is narrower than 650px:</p>

<pre>small</pre>

  <p>I want this pre to be wider than 650px no matter what the
  viewport size is:</p>

<pre>this pre should be wider than the text above
    <span>wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz</span>
</pre>
</body>
```

Here are the key points:

- Everything but `pre`s must be constrained to a maximum width of 650px.
- The width of a `pre` block should either be the width of its content or 650px, whichever is greater.  No wrapping, no scrolling.  Note that this means a `pre` could be wider than its parent's width.
- Solution needs to work on at least latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari (macOS and iOS), Edge, and IE 11.
- I can't modify *anything* within the body tags, though I can wrap the contents with additional HTML if need be.

Here's a screenshot of what I'd like to happen, note the second `pre` that is wider than its parent:

[image]

I got as far as trying [`pre { display: inline-block; }`](https://jsfiddle.net/1hd03o1o/) but this doesn't work in Safari.  (The white space is significant to reproducing this Safari problem!)

I feel like a lot of people are having trouble understanding that I'm asking for a good way to make `pre` blocks wider than their parent when the `pre` content is wider than the parent.

Alternatively, I'll take any other sane way to have `pre` blocks behave like `min-width: 650px; max-width: fit-content;`, while the rest of the content on the page is `max-width: 650px;`.

Comment: OK, I've done my best to trim it down and hopefully make it more understandable?  I've also got a screenshot?  Sorry, I'm not sure how to make this more clear.  I just don't want my code samples to be cut off at 650px, and I definitely don't want `overflow: scroll` because I find nested scrollable elements annoying.

Comment: I didn't really get a chance to see what your original question was like, but this rewrite seems pretty clear to me. The illustration helps. I cleaned up most of the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up more-or-less solving this.  The basic approach is not to constrain the width of `body`, but to constrain all children of `body` instead, then relax `pre`s.  (Feel free to choose a container further down from the body, e.g. your `div#main` or something.)

Note that I used `display: table` on `pre` because `inline-block` seemed to prevent margin collapsing, which was important to me elsewhere in my real use of this, if not important for this simplified example.

I'm feeling pretty confident that Safari/WebKit has a bug (that Chrome has not!), so using JavaScript was unavoidable.

I think this behaves somewhat less nice on browsers that don't (yet) support `max-width: fit-content`, but it does something acceptable there.

SO snippet below, but the CSS looks slightly prettier, IMHO, in Sass, which is how I originally wrote this solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrZVrg

```js
function patchCodeSamplesForWebKit() {
    for (const codeElem of document.querySelectorAll("pre")) {
        if (codeElem.offsetWidth <= codeElem.parentNode.offsetWidth) {
            // No problem with this one.
            continue;
        }
        const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(codeElem,
                                                     NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
        let textNode;
        while ((textNode = treeWalker.nextNode())) {
            // console.log("Pre fix considering:", textNode);
            const i = textNode.textContent.indexOf("\n");
            if (i >= 0) {
                // console.log("Splitting a text node for pre fix.");
                textNode.splitText(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    // console.log("Completed pre fixes for safari.");
}

if (/\bAppleWebKit\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    && !/\bChrom(e|ium)\b/.test(navigator.userAgent))
{
    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
        patchCodeSamplesForWebKit();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
                                  patchCodeSamplesForWebKit);
    }
    console.log("Configured pre fix for WebKit/Safari.");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  body {
    min-width: 650px;
    max-width: 650px;
    max-width: fit-content;
  }
}

body > * {
  max-width: 650px;
}

body > pre {
  display: table;
  max-width: none;
  min-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  body > pre {
    min-width: 650px;
  }
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

pre {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This is a sufficiently long paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae hic rei publicae vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Ut id aliis narrare gestiant? Cur iustitia laudatur? Nummus in Croesi divitiis obscuratur, pars
    est tamen divitiarum.</p>

  <p>This pre should be as wide as the first paragraph, even when the viewport is narrower than 650px:</p>

  <pre>small</pre>

  <p>I want this pre to be wider than 650px no matter what the viewport size is:</p>

  <pre>this pre should be wider than the text above
        <span>wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz</span>
    </pre>
</body>
```